# Subtract days or years from new java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: groovy, soapui

**Application:**  SoapUI XML Resquest

I could swear this worked at one time where I use the below:

```
${=(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format( new Date() )}
```

To Subtract or Add I would add enclose the -# or +# like so:

```
 ${=${=(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format( new Date() )}-1
```

The result of the -1 is showing up as 1982

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Why is it taking away the -MM-dd part?
2. Why is it subtracting 23 years for -1

**GOAL:**

To be able to subtract from sysdate and the request show in yyyy-MM-dd format
i.e. if I want someone to be 65 years old - i want to subtract from sysdate to get that.

Again this is a SoapUI tag I'm populating the expression in.

Comment: Why did you tag JavaScript if this is referring to Java? Two totally different programming languages.

Comment: which language is this? above line is not valid syntax in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the brackets misplaced! Let me break it down for you:

```
def yesterday = new Date() - 1
def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
def yesterdayFormatted = sdf.format(yesterday)
```

If you want it in a SoapUI property one liner:

```
${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date() - 1)}
```

Note that you can achieve the exact same thing with (slightly more compact):

```
${=String.format('%tF', new Date() - 1)}
```

Docs for the [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Maybe you can help me because this is killing me this morning. Using SoapUI Pro and I have the following code in it. ${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(new Date()-6)} but what it is generating is '2016-02-32' is not a valid value for 'date'

Comment: @Elijah Do you have a new question?

Comment: @SiKing I think I may have gotten the answer at a thread I started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132272/how-to-get-in-soapui-the-date-minus-days/35132759?noredirect=1#comment57989941_35132759 I'll let you know as well.

Comment: @SiKing just an FYI that the issue is resolved and I had posted several examples of how to format the code. This was done for use in SoapUI Pro.