# How to get in SoapUI the date minus days?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, soapui

Before thinking this is a duplicate please read.

I have been reading through the posts here and elsewhere but cannot figure out why the date is coming out invalid in the first place.

I am using SoapUI Pro to make calls and have placed in the XML that submits some code reference in order to create dates in the past but I need them to be relative to today not something that will be in the future or distant past so I have used the following

```
${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(new Date()-6);}
```

When I submit my call to the Web Service I get back this error.

> '2016-02-32' is not a valid value for 'date'

Can someone please explain why this is occurring? 
and what am I needing to correct this?

Ultimately I need to be able to do two things.

1. Create a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD 6 days in the past
2. Create a date time in the format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX

Greatly appreciate some assistance on this.
Am I not to use the Date?
I have seen some that are using the Calendar and new references to Java 8, it is just a time crunch thing this morning and I did not want to go down any rabbit holes to track possible things that may be an issue as the servers are not using Java 8 at this time.

Comment: I had the wrong format specified. See below for the link to the helpful guide that shows the correct date format syntax to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

```
${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -6); new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime());}
```

you can use it as well for the date and time, just replace the formatting string.

The corect pattern for formatting date is `yyyy-MM-dd` (see [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc)

- y - means the current year
- Y - means week year, can be different then year for the first and last week in year ([explained difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat))
- d - day in month
- D - day in year

Answer based on [How to subtract X day from a Date object  in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java)

Comment: I have been working this the 40 minutes. Trying to find what is going on in the service. Even using the above without the subtraction of days ${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD").format(cal.getTime());} the server keeps responding with '2016-02-32' is not a valid value for 'date'.      If I just HARD CODE the date of 2016-02-01 then it will go through just fine. What gives?

Comment: I tested it locally with SoapUI non pro version 5.0.0, with a mocked service inside the SoapUI and it was working just fine. Maybe there is some issue with: your SoupUI version or maybe you have set as default some non Gregorian calendar? Try to set a mock service within SoapUI and verify if the generated request is as expected. If the request is correct then maybe there is an issue on server side?

Comment: The thing I have not noticed before is that the date formatting pattern is incorrect. Should be 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Comment: Thank you MJar, I'll give that a try once I get back to my office.

Comment: Excellent catch. I did not see that at all. It just happened to be working fine this past month because all of the days were indeed valid. 32 is not a valid day of a month. Thank you so very much for your help. I'm sure this will correct the issue I'm having in SoapUI.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in SoapUI v5.3.0:

`${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date() - 6)}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @MJar.
These are formats I have used within the XML that I submit via SoapUI Pro and work!

**Note:** The code is all on a single line just because that is how I did it to put in the XML and not have multiple lines.

*2016-02-02*

```
${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime());}
```

*2016-02-03T09:54:55.866-05:00*

```
${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").format(cal.getTime());}
```

*Or make it a day in the past (this case 6 days ago)*

```
${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -6); new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(cal.getTime());}
```

Answer (score 0):

${=def now=new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
And if you need it to be yesterday or a future date, just as +x to Date()
example
${=def now=new Date()+10;now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}

Comment: Please format your answer and also add explanation.